# Scrape internal links with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have written a python code to fetch the web-page corresponding to a given url, and parses all the links on that page into a repository of links. Next, it fetches the contents of any of the url from the repository just created, parses the links from this new content into the repository and continues this process for all links in the repository until stopped or after a given number of links are fetched.

Here code:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import itertools
import random


class Crawler(object):
"""docstring for Crawler"""

def __init__(self):

    self.soup = None                                        # Beautiful Soup object
    self.current_page   = "http://www.python.org/"          # Current page's address
    self.links          = set()                             # Queue with every links fetched
    self.visited_links  = set()

    self.counter = 0 # Simple counter for debug purpose

def open(self):

    # Open url
    print self.counter , ":", self.current_page
    res = urllib2.urlopen(self.current_page)
    html_code = res.read()
    self.visited_links.add(self.current_page) 

    # Fetch every links
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html_code)

    page_links = []
    try :
        page_links = itertools.ifilter(  # Only deal with absolute links 
                                        lambda href: 'http://' in href,
                                            ( a.get('href') for a in self.soup.findAll('a') )  )
    except Exception: # Magnificent exception handling
        pass



    # Update links 
    self.links = self.links.union( set(page_links) ) 



    # Choose a random url from non-visited set
    self.current_page = random.sample( self.links.difference(self.visited_links),1)[0]
    self.counter+=1


def run(self):

    # Crawl 3 webpages (or stop if all url has been fetched)
    while len(self.visited_links) < 3 or (self.visited_links == self.links):
        self.open()

    for link in self.links:
        print link



if __name__ == '__main__':

C = Crawler()
C.run()
```

This code does not fetch internal links (only absolute formed hyperlinks)

**How to fetch Internal links that starts with   '/' or '#' or '.'**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, your code kind of already tells you what's going on.  In your lambda you are only grabbing absolute links that start with http:// (which you are not grabbing https FWIW).  You should grab all of the links and check to see if they start with http+ or not.  If they don't, then they are a relative link, and since you know what the `current_page` is then you can use that to create an absolute link.

Here's a modification to your code.  Excuse my Python as it's a little rusty, but I ran it and it worked in Python 2.7 for me.  You'll want to clean it up and add some edge/error detection, but you get the gist:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import itertools
import random
import urlparse


class Crawler(object):
"""docstring for Crawler"""

def __init__(self):
    self.soup = None                                        # Beautiful Soup object
    self.current_page   = "http://www.python.org/"          # Current page's address
    self.links          = set()                             # Queue with every links fetched
    self.visited_links  = set()

    self.counter = 0 # Simple counter for debug purpose

def open(self):

    # Open url
    print self.counter , ":", self.current_page
    res = urllib2.urlopen(self.current_page)
    html_code = res.read()
    self.visited_links.add(self.current_page)

    # Fetch every links
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code)

    page_links = []
    try :
        for link in [h.get('href') for h in self.soup.find_all('a')]:
            print "Found link: '" + link + "'"
            if link.startswith('http'):
                page_links.append(link)
                print "Adding link" + link + "\n"
            elif link.startswith('/'):
                parts = urlparse.urlparse(self.current_page)
                page_links.append(parts.scheme + '://' + parts.netloc + link)
                print "Adding link " + parts.scheme + '://' + parts.netloc + link + "\n"
            else:
                page_links.append(self.current_page+link)
                print "Adding link " + self.current_page+link + "\n"

    except Exception, ex: # Magnificent exception handling
        print ex

    # Update links 
    self.links = self.links.union( set(page_links) )

    # Choose a random url from non-visited set
    self.current_page = random.sample( self.links.difference(self.visited_links),1)[0]
    self.counter+=1

def run(self):

    # Crawl 3 webpages (or stop if all url has been fetched)
    while len(self.visited_links) < 3 or (self.visited_links == self.links):
        self.open()

    for link in self.links:
        print link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    C = Crawler()
    C.run()
```

Comment: I already know what you are suggesting to me. I tried but unable to handle all internal links scuccessfully so can u make the changes in code and say me what i have to do

Answer (score 1):

chage condition in lambda:

```
page_links = itertools.ifilter(  # Only deal with absolute links 
                                        lambda href: 'http://' in href or href.startswith('/') or href.startswith('#') or href.startswith('.'),
                                            ( a.get('href') for a in  self.soup.findAll('a') )  )
```

Comment: I know i have to change to change the condition but what it should be so that it can handle all type of internal links.